# Text box on flagging dialog is too big

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The text box with "Something is not quite right?" is too big it sticks out. I'm sure this is easy to fix :)

[image: The text box with "Something is not quite right?" is too big it sticks out.]

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.